# ws02 5.0.0 missing sessionIndex in SAML 2.0 Response

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I just installed and configured wso2 IS. I have a small Java application acting as the SP. I am using the resident IDp. I am able to send a request and get a response back. For some reason, sessionIndex attribute of the AuthnStatement is missing. I understand this is an optional attribute but how do I configure my wso2Is and/or my SP and IDp to ensure it gets sent as part of the response. Here is the response I get.

```
<saml2p:Response Destination="http://localhost:8080" ID="igagmdgmjlflgcljianclnnpfkfilpbnfomonkmn" InResponseTo="ajbhplbldnpgoigiegdmmhlhlblmfjcbhpbcfpnn" IssueInstant="2015-02-09T15:20:52.141Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">localhost</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#igagmdgmjlflgcljianclnnpfkfilpbnfomonkmn"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>gVmD3/tfB4suknjA89b0UilGxD4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>c8Z4xjKjo05XfawLfSHCsA2L6DBEruI4nI0hvxm2yY//tAXgFdsh1ezkeJEMxB8enRR9Lh1Vhb4IQQ6BFhysEtdrP6MqQeu26ehwY5VbkhU3YTzut3m8/eVyL9XL6go8HiIUamRXTIELTwdjagoACVJ6KYPMApIB0+lqB1WERTU=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></saml2p:Status><saml2:Assertion ID="hlfiehajebijcoclljpaenpkaodpjedjndoimpdd" IssueInstant="2015-02-09T15:20:52.141Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#hlfiehajebijcoclljpaenpkaodpjedjndoimpdd"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>pTqbRLq9GTnyKNu4WYuX+XaCDVo=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>Fsc0bdW7QYdX1VNpeMrjH+ETZA64WvodZhS+cPcCkWg+Azt1fZG8SaCHq6heqwx2tNjk5BUpHHNeOYUbcn7ztR6JQXfNynO0WG2D9096St5FcngoFqCL5X2Xa5XKdIKDMH/5UniIniKvm7XY62thx9+f8O0oD9/WhWbeW+jYv2A=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">joebloggs</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ajbhplbldnpgoigiegdmmhlhlblmfjcbhpbcfpnn" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-09T15:25:52.141Z" Recipient="http://localhost:8080"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2015-02-09T15:20:52.141Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-09T15:25:52.141Z"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>localhost</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-02-09T15:20:52.142Z"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement/></saml2:Assertion></saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: Can you add to your question what's the code you're using to send and receive the request, and what does the request look like?

Answer (score 1):

I enabled the “Enable Single Logout :” in SAML2 SSO issuer configuration. It looks like if it is enabled, it returns the “sessionIndex” attribute.